# Expressing "feed off of" in German

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

Quick question: I am looking for the best way to express "feed off of" in a figurative sense in German. Here are some examples:

1. The soldiers feed off of the courage of the general.
2. The band feeds off of the energy of the crowd.

Here is my attempt at a translation:

1. Die Soldaten zehren von dem Mut des Generals.
2. Die Band zehrt von der Energie des Publikums.

Does "zehren von" work here? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, *to feed on/off sth.* is used without *of*. And yes: in a figurative sense, the expression can be translated to *von etw. zehren*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sometimes native speakers make mistakes, although the "of" seemed very natural to me...but maybe my university English teacher would say it is incorrect? Good question.

Answer (score 9):

*zehren* is relatively old-fashioned and also implies a scarceness of supply. It does somewhat fit, though.

*leben von* is the expression to use and can also be used figuratively for non-animated subjects.

> Das Wohnzimmer lebt von den üppigen Stuckverzierungen an der Zimmerdecke
>
> Der Titel lebt vom starken Bass, der den Rythmus treibt (music)